# Paperclip avatars image missing if user didnt uploaded image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using Paperclip for uploading the Profile image in my application (rails)

My User model is having a

```
 has_attached_file :avatar,
   :url => "/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
   :path => ":rails_root/public/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
   :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :small => "100x100>", :thumb => "50x50>", :micro => "30x30>" }
```

In my VIew If i have a profile image uploaded then its pointing correctly as

/avatars/1/thumb/iamge

BUt if the image is not there if they didn't uploaded in that case its pointing as

/avatars/thumb/missing.png which doesn't have any image.

Please give suggestions what to do if the user didnt uploaded any profile image..

Comment: Do you have an image for `/avatars/thumb/missing.png`? This would be Paperclip's way of displaying a default image if the user didn't upload one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails missing image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253908/rails-missing-image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a default image and put it there and name it `missing.png`. It is like extra functionality :)

Comment: inside public/avatars i have created folder called thumb and an image for missing.png .. BUt i need to do the same for small -> missing and for all styles .. Is that a good way of doing . Or am i doing in a wrong way

Comment: That is the perfect way to do it. For every style image you want a missing image with another resolution.

Comment: @MichaelKoper you can use some if conditions like if @user.avatar_file_name.blank?. I mean to say if their is no image uploaded then you did not need to show anything.